# Не могу запустить программу на С++ с использованием SFML 2.0

Tags: c++, sfml

Пытаюсь разобраться с графикой в С++ . Использую SFML 2.0 , Code Blocks , GNU GCC. Установил согласно инструкции на сайте и заголовочные файлы нормально подключаются однако попытка создать пустое окно выдает ошибку . Код

```
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main()
    {
        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
        return 0;
    }
```

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Comment: Какая ошибка? Времени компиляции? Это то, что на рисунке? Попробуйте сами рассмотреть текст и поймите, почему вам стоит привести лог в текстовом виде.

Comment: ЗЫ: Если меня не подводит зрение, у вас ошибка компоновки. Посмотрите в описание библиотеки, какую библиотеку вам надо подключить.